# Alternative Range/Cell Addressing in Google Sheets Formulas/Functions

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

```
=AVERAGE("M1"&":"&Address(10,13,4))
```

I am trying to take the average of (part of a much larger formula, this is just the par I'm stuck on) a range of values. I would like to have the first cell reference a normal reference, like above: column M, row 1. I would then like the second cell reference in the range to be a formula/function, in the example above column M, row 10.

I would like to eventually replace the "10" above with another formula/function, but that's not the problem right now.

When I try the formula above, I get a DIV/0! error, as if there is /some/ range being passed to Average, but it's not the correct one. Modifying the address function to some other arbitrary set of values yields the same result.

**I'm also not married to the address function**; if there is a way to manipulate the second reference in the range with a different function, I'm all ears.

Edit: I found my answer doing a deeper search through Excel forums. if wrapped in "Indirect" the text within Average's parentheses acts as a range, as you would expect. Here is an example:

```
=indirect("M1"&":"&Address(RIGHT(A1,3),16,4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I found my answer doing a deeper search through Excel forums. if wrapped in `Indirect` the text within Average's parentheses acts as a range, as you would expect. Here is an example:

```
=indirect("M1"&":"&Address(RIGHT(A1,3),16,4))
```

You can replace the address function with another function or value. So long as the end result of whatever you put in indirect looks like a cell or range reference, indirect will work (from my understanding).

Answer (score 0):

A bit like in Excel, you can use:

```
=AVERAGE(M1:INDEX(M:M,10))
```